# How can I save the SSIS design view as an image?

Tags: ssis

I'm quite new to SSIS and have taken on a quite large ETL project from a previous colleague. Id like to document the .dtsx Flow and basically just want to export or save an image of the Designer view in SSIS (i.e. the flow diagram bit). Can this be done? I've searched but have'nt been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a screen capture program that supports scrolling windows.  Although your image will be very large, you won't lose any of the details that you may get if you zoom out.  There's a [blog post here](http://www.writersua.com/articles/capturetools/index.html) that compares a variety of screen capture programs.  According to the reviewer, the following programs support auto scrolling of long windows:

1. FastStone Capture 6.5
2. HyperSnap 6.7
3. MadCapture 5
4. RoboScreen Capture 2
5. SnagIt 9.1.

Personally, SnagIt is my screen capture program of choice.  I've been using it for 8 years now and I originally started using it specifically for the auto scrolling window screen capture feature.  I have used it to take screen shots of large SSIS packages, so I can attest to the fact that it works for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Other than taking printscreens of it and editing it i am not aware of any built-in tool to do that

Comment: Cheers, i thought as much but that is a pain. Its quite a large flow diagram and the print screen would be too small if i fit it all in. Guess there's not much i can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not adverse to paying for it, there is BiDocumentor from PragmaticWorks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File -> Print -> Select Print to PDF option, and that's it!

(not an image, but pdf is actually more convenient for quite large packages )

Comment: N.B. You need a PDF application installed for this.